# TYPO3 fluid: count filtered iterations

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I know it's not recommended practice, data filtering is supposed to be done in the <strike>controller</strike> repository. But this happens to me quite often:

You have a list of data and want to display it regarding some criteria (in the example, `plugin.myext.settings.year = 2015`):

```
<f:for each="{events}" as="event">
  <f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: event.date, format: 'Y')}=={settings.year}">
  {event.name}
  </f:if>
</f:for>
```

This is a nice and simple way to get all events from 2015.

BUT how to count those ad-hoc-filtered events? 
To output something like: **123 Events in 2015**.

`<f:count>{events}</f:count>` won't respect the condition. Is it possible to keep some counter running, to at least be able to output the number of hits at the bottom? Or no way at all (except a custom viewhelper)?

Comment: I think you should consider taking the effort to filter critera in your repository, not in the view. scnr.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, custom viewhelper, would be your only option for the count.
You might have a chance to use vhs though, https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/ vhs:variable.get / set.

```
<vhs:variable.set('eventCount', 0) />    
<f:for each="{events}" as="event">
      <f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: event.date, format: 'Y')}=={settings.year}">
         <vhs:variable.set('eventCount' ,{variable.get('eventCount')}+1) />
      {event.name}
      </f:if>
    </f:for>
<span>count: <vhs:variable.get('eventCount) />
```

This might work, but I doubt fluid allows addition.

But if you could add javascript you could do a count of the list elements.

Javascript using jquery would look something like:

```
var eventCount = jQuery('listId .event').length;
var countHtml = jQuery('<div />', {id: 'eventCount', html: "event count:" + eventCount});
jQuery('.tx_extkey').append(countHtml);
```

Comment: sounds nice! I'll try it!

Comment: Up to 7.6 you can not calculate directly in fluid. You need an additional VH to do the math. But the cleanest solution (everyone would expect it there and the runtime and memory consumption would be least) is to do the filtering and the count in your repository.

Comment: Just to complete this (while the repository is the right way): how would I write `<vhs:variable.set('eventCount' ,{variable.get('eventCount')}+1) />` using `v:math.sum`? Something like `<vhs:variable.set('eventCount' ,{v:math.sum({variable.get('eventCount')},1)} />` – can you nest VHs in inline notation that way?

Comment: there are multiple possibilities to nest VHs. that is one possibility. Be carefull if you nest VHs inside of strings, as you might need to escape the included parameter if they are strings. (this could be a good question with a lot of answers on itself)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an getter "getYear" to your event Model. Than you can use the `GroupedForViewHelper` to get your events groupped by year:

```
<f:groupedFor each="{events}" as="eventsByYear" groupBy="year" groupKey="year">
  <f:if condition="{year} == {settings.year}">
    <f:then>
       <h3>{eventsByYear -> f:count()} events in {year}</h3>
       <ul>
         <f:for each="{eventsByYear}" as="event">
           <li>{event.name}</li>
         </f:for>
       </ul>
    </f:then>
  </f:if>
</f:groupedFor>
```

But as yourself have noticed: To filter events make an own filter in your EventRepository according to your needs.

Comment: Out of curiosity: in the model, would the getter plug into the existing "date" field and pull the year out of it, that's what you mean, right? Without adding a "year" column to the db

Comment: Right, the year getter is only to get the year as decimal from the date field without an extra column.

Comment: Thanks! It's an interesting possibility.